# Display a vue component inside iframe

Tags: vue.js, iframe

I want to display some of my pages (Vue components) on a modal, exactly the same identical components or routes that I've been using in my project, but the only difference is this time they won't be on the whole page but on a modal. I though I could use `iframe` but when I try to put the component name to `:src` attribute of iframe, Vue gives me `<compName> is defined but not used` error. Is there a way to put a component inside an iframe? I tried to use 3rd party npm packages like `vue-friendly-iframe` but couldn't get what I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Putting a Vue component inside of an iframe instead of giving a source path to it. For example <iframe :src="myComponent"></iframe> When I do that, Vue says myComponent is defined but not used because it doesn't accept this usage of the imported component.